# How to pass multiple waypoint to standard google map app in android through intent for navigation ?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent

I have done some research and i found that adding multiple destination is possible through google map website and one can send the entire navigation plan to google map android app it works perfect.

But in my case i want to generate multiple destination navigation url dynamically through my app and pass it via intent to open google map app in phone.
 How can this be achieved any ideas would be helpfull .

Comment: You can only pass two points: start and destination.

Comment: it is possible in website then there must be way to do the same for phone also and more over google map app in phone is cable of handling multiple destination so there must be a way to send it dynamically

Comment: Hi @ANAND PURUSHOTTAM, any luck with navigation using waypoints?

Comment: I'm at the same problem right now. do you found any solution for this?

Comment: use this https://stackoverflow.com/a/46337590/1713415

Answer (score 6):

You may generate multiple destination by requesting  ['*https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?*'](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#DirectionsRequests). However, you are limited up to 8 waypoints. To get more waypoints for a request, you'll need to get [Google Maps API for Work](https://developers.google.com/maps/premium/) which will allow you up to 23 waypoints.

Regarding Google Maps Intents, in order to launch Maps with an intent, you must first create an Intent object specifying its action, URI and package. For more details, check this link: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/intents