# Adding multiple way points in Google Maps via Android Intent

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent

As a part of navigation in my app, I am re-directing my app to Google Maps along with the lats and longs. I have already succeeded in passing the source and destination and making it open in Google Maps directly.

```
Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=9.883456,78.120150");
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,gmmIntentUri);
mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
startActivity(mapIntent);
```

But my **question** is **how do I pass multiple points** to Google Maps via intent. Recently Google introduced adding multiple destinations in the mobile version of the Google Map app and I presume that its available in the Google Directions API but I don't want to take the twisted path by integrating Google Directions in my app, I'd rather take the highway to Google Maps.

I have been searching a lot on this topic but all I find is the following but that doesnt work either.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=st.%20louis,mo&daddr=washington,dc%20to:chicago,il%20to:new%20york,ny"));
startActivity(intent);
```

The above code works only when we open it in Chrome but I want it to open in Google Maps and even adding a `mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");` doesn't work but its kinda obvious that the above uri passed is a URL that's available in Google Maps of web version.

Any insights or any ideas on how this can be achieved will be more than welcomed.

**P.S:** Can this be achieved at all ?????

Comment: This question seems similar to this [SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35772128/how-to-pass-multiple-waypoint-to-standard-google-map-app-in-android-through-inte).

Answer (score 6):

1. Contruct URL = https://www.google.co.in/maps/dir/18.6121132,73.707989/18.642344,73.707880/18.652344,73.727880/18.6530132,73.7270

   In above URL

   source = 18.6121132,73.707989

   waypoint1 = 18.642344,73.707880

   waypoint2 = 18.652344,73.727880

   destination = 18.6530132,73.7270
2. Call Google Map Intent URI

   `Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("https://www.google.co.in/maps/dir/18.6121132,73.707989/18.5,73.7/18.8,73.71");
   Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri); 
   mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
   startActivity(mapIntent);`

I have tested it with multiple way points and it worked for me.
I hope this will help others

Note: It works only on latest Android Google Maps application

Comment: How you wrote these values in Uri.parse "18.6121132,73.707989/18.5,73.7/18.8,73.71" need clarification.

Comment: Are those the latitudes and longitudes?

Comment: Yes correct those are latitudes and longitudes